Can one decompose quasi finite morphism as a composition of an open immersion and a finite morphism?
Can one decompose quasi-finite separated morphism of schemes as a composition of an open immersion and a finite morphism?
I am willing to assume that all the involved schemes are Noetherian.

Yes (without noetherian hypotheses). This is a strong version of Zariski's main theorem: see EGA IV, Corollary 18.12.13.

Or see [Tag 05K0].

Thank both of you very much. Does any of you want to post both references as an answer so I can accept it?
